# Trying to add null character to end of a char array before strcpy

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Working on a problem where I have to read data from a file into a struct using .

The file is organized so that there is a name, a few lines of ASCII art terminated by a # and a rating. Here is an example

```
Sample Name
( S )
( S )
# 5
```

I have my struct set up like this:

```
typedef struct
 {
   char* name;
   char* art;
   int rating;
 }CASE;
```

When I compile my source, I keep getting the following warnings:

```
multiple-character character constant
overflow in implicit constant conversion
```

on this line `buffer[artCount] = '/0';` where artCount is strlen of the buffer itself.

I'm simply adding a null character to the end of a character array to prepare for a strcpy. Is there something wrong with my logic here?

function:

```
/*CASE* all is an empty array of CASE structs*/
void readFile(FILE* FPin, CASE* all)
{
  CASE* walker = all;
  int count = 0;
  int artCount;
  char buffer[160];

  if((FPin = fopen("art.txt", "r")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error opening file.");
    exit(100);  
  }

 walker->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

 /*Reads in the name*/
 while(fgets(walker->name, 100, FPin) != NULL)
  {

 /*Reads in the art*/
   while(fscanf(FPin, "%c", buffer) != '#');

   artCount = strlen(buffer);
   buffer[artCount] = '/0';
   walker->art = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*160);
   strcpy(walker->art, buffer);

/*Reads in the rating*/

     fscanf(FPin, "%d", &walker->rating);

   count++;
   walker++;
 } 

  fclose(FPin);
  return;
}
```

Comment: The escape sequence is `\0` – **backslash** zero

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 by the C standard.

Comment: 6 years and nobody has pointed out that `artCount = strlen(buffer); buffer[artCount] = '\0'` (even with the right `\\`) does nothing?

Comment: @trentcl This is so old and I haven't touched C since this class project :P Thanks for pointing it out anyway

Comment: @Huy Not really for you, more for future readers of the question. Mostly I was just surprised :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The constant should be `'\0'` (with a backslash), not `'/0'` (with a forward slash).